# Get list of modified / new / removed files using org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.GitClient

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

How can I get the list of modified, new, and removed files using org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.GitClient ?

Right now, I'm doing something like:

```
String status = ((CliGitAPIImpl) gitClient).launchCommand("ls-files", "--deleted", "--modified", "--others", SOME_DIRECTORY);
for (String toCommit : status.split("\\R")) {
   gitClient.add(toCommit);
}
```

but I don't like this approach. first, because it relies on CliGitAPIImpl (and other Jenkins installations could use other classes, like for example RemoteGitImpl which doesn't implement the launchCommand method). second, I'm already using gitClient to create branches, add files to be committed, commit, push, etc., therefore I would prefer to use some API rather than just calling launchCommand method.

--
Thanks,
Jose